# Ruby on Rails: The stringex gem: Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, i'm using stringex to convert non roman characters, to their roman pronunciation equivalent...
for example, it will change 日本語 to nihongo....

And I'm using these as URLs... and when the URLs aren't using the roman alphabet, ruby breaks.

Now... this works on my machine... but not on a co-worker's machine... we both have stringex 1.1.0

and ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out... friendly_id was't at the same version on both machines